# wrong value from db c++

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

im working on a project in c++ and i am working with db.
the relevant table looks like this:
t_players_answers:

game_id ---- integer pk

username ---- text pk

question_id ---- integer pk

player_answer ---- text

is_correct ---- integer

answer_time ---- integer

i want to get the avg time of question so i did this:

```
double DBmanagement::avgQTime(string name) const{
    string sql = "select avg(answer_time) from t_players_answers where username='" + name + "'";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    double re;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, sql.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL);
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
    re= sqlite3_column_double(stmt, 0);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    return re;
}
```

when i am trying to do the line

```
select avg(answer_time) from t_players_answers where username='[name]';
```

in the sqlite3 app it gives the correct answer but this function does not. i couldnt find a pattern in the return values in this function.
this problem, of returning wrong values, happens to me in few similar function except this one.

can someone help me and point out where and what im doing wrong here?

Comment: Check all function calls for errors.

Comment: @CL. it doesnt show any errors in any step

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)